Is possible to change color of focused NavigationDestination in NavigationBar in Flet/Python?
I'm working with Flet on Android App and I need one functionality.
I have this code
def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.padding = 0
    page.window_width = 400
    page.window_height = 850
    page.window_resizable = False
    page.window_maximizable = False
    page.theme_mode = ft.ThemeMode.LIGHT
    page.window_center()
    page.title = "My APP"

    page.navigation_bar = ft.CupertinoNavigationBar(
        bgcolor=ft.colors.GREY_100,
        inactive_color=ft.colors.GREY,
        active_color=ft.colors.BLACK,
        destinations=[
            ft.NavigationDestination(icon=ft.icons.EXPLORE, label="Explore"),
            ft.NavigationDestination(icon=ft.icons.HOME, label="Home"),
            ft.NavigationDestination(
                icon=ft.icons.BOOKMARK_BORDER,
                selected_icon=ft.icons.BOOKMARK,
                label="Info",
            ),
        ]
    )
    page.add(ft.Text("Body!"))

ft.app(target=main)

And I need to set different 'active_color' for every NavigationDestination - when EXPLORE is choosen, then it's icon should have red color, when HOME then the color of icon should be blue etc.
Is there any possibillity? I can use other navigation bar if necessity.
Thank you all!
I tried to search on Google or ask ChatGPT, but nothing worked.
I also created function which uses lambda e and e.control.seslected_index and if statement to change colors, but it doesn't work.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
